# Hello I want to make a way to make mousePressedOver in code.org game lab so you only click once

Tags: code.org

So in my CS class I have been working on code.org I wanted to make something but it doesnt work because mousePressedOver is not one click.
I don't really know anymore coding so this is why I need help, I couldn't find any answers online.

```
// framerate 
World.frameRate = 120;

// sound
playSound("baller.mp3");

// variables+sprites
var balloon = createSprite(200, 200);
balloon.setAnimation("balloon");
balloon.scale = 0.1;
var baller = createSprite(200, 200);
baller.setAnimation("baller");

look at the comment where it says secret that is where I need help.

//draw loop 
function draw() {

// background
background("white");

  // scale and visible
  balloon.scale = balloon.scale + 0.03;
  baller.visible = false;
  
  // if statement
 if (balloon.scale > 0.5) {
    baller.visible = true;
    balloon.visible = false;
  }
  
    // secret
if (mousePressedOver(baller))  {
  var shhhh = createSprite(200, 200);
shhhh.setAnimation("thing");
shhhh.scale = 0.3;
  textSize(25);
 text("You werent supposed to see this...", 20,50);
 baller.visible = false;
}


   // draw sprites
  drawSprites();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `if (mousePressedOver(baller) && mouseWentDown("leftButton")) {}`  to check if the Sprite is clicked once.

Edited:

Define a boolean variable ;

```
var showHiddenText = false;
```

Add this after you define `background("white");`

```
if(showHiddenText){
  text("You werent supposed to see this...", 20,50)
}
```

Control it by changing the boolean value;

```
if (mousePressedOver(baller) && mouseDown())  {
 showHiddenText = true;
}
```

Comment: Another problem I have is that when you click the sprite the text only appears for a 
split second and then dissapears and the baller sprite is not visible for like a split second. So basically the if then statement doesent do what its supposed to

Comment: If statement works as it's supposed to it creates text when the sprite is clicked. If you want the text to stay you need to define the text outside the if statement and control its visibility with mouseDown(). In this case, we shouldn't use the if statement in the first place but onClick for js or onEvent for App Lab don't have a similar function in the Game Lab. Check the answer I edited.

Comment: Thanks a lot it helped! I'm not really an experienced coder.